# Running a single command on multiple files using Ant

Tags: javascript, ant, handlebars.js

I'm trying to compile a bunch of handlebars templates into a single compiled file using ant.  I have a number of folders that each contain about 4 templates each and I want to compile these all into one file.  With folders like:

```
folder01
  |- templates
       |- f1_01.handlebars
       |- f1_02.handlebars
       |- f1_03.handlebars
       |- f1_04.handlebars
folder02
  |- templates
       |- f2_01.handlebars
       |- f2_02.handlebars
       |- f2_03.handlebars
       |- f2_04.handlebars
build.xml
```

I essentially want to run the command:

```
handlebars **/templates/*.handlebars -f compiled-templates.js
```

I have tried the following but it only seems to include 1 file in the output js file.

```
<macrodef name="handlebars">
    <attribute name="target"/>
    <sequential>
        <apply executable="${handlebars}" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="." includes="**/templates/">
                <include name="*.handlebars"/>
            </fileset>
            <arg value="-f compiled-templates.js"/>
        </apply>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Also, strangely, the output file starts with a space character, which I can't seem to get rid of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using a `<concat>` task, to create one file out of all the templates, and running the executable once on that file.

```
<concat destfile="all.handlebars" append="true">
    <fileset dir="." includes="**/templates/">
        <include name="*.handlebars"/>
    </fileset>
</concat>
```

Comment: don't you think this answer is wrong? because if you concat all the templates then it will be considered as a single template file. When you precompile them properly it creates a single file but within that file it has proper separation between those templates. Now in your case there will be no separation between the templates in that single output file. Hence Handlebars.runtime.js wont be able to find the exact template file it needs.

Comment: This was exactly the right answer for the problem, and all of the templates were able to be used correctly and remain in use to this day, so the separation is not required.  Can you please remove your downvote, or at least wait for a response to your "don't you think this answer is wrong" question.  Have you bothered to test this solution before making assertions to its correctness?  Judging by the language used, it looks doubtful.

Comment: I also notice that you didn't provide your "correct" answer to the problem or upvote any of the other suggestions.

Comment: sorry about the language. I checked the solution and it was not working for me. And i cannot remove my vote. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am posting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot on stackoverflow and, more importantly, reading the docs i came up with this solution which works.

```
<echo level="info" message="Pre Compiling templates" />
<apply parallel="true" failonerror="true" executable="node">
  <arg value="${webclient.dir.build}/node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars" />
  <srcfile />
  <fileset dir="${webclient}/app/templates" includes="**/*.handlebars"/>
  <arg line="-f ${webclient}/app/templates/handlebars.templates.js -m -a" />
</apply>
```

Comment: so basically this will execute node ./webclient/build/node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars <list of templates> -f webclient/app/templates/handlebars.templates.js

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
...
<arg line="-f compiled-templates.js"/>
...
```

instead of :

```
...
<arg value="-f compiled-templates.js"/>
...
```

Comment: Accept answer or upvote if my suggested solution worked for you !?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<script>` task where you can embed Javascript or Groovy code that does the iteration work. It is a good practise to call some shorts scripts as a help for such problems as they are usually more expressive than the tricky XML-loop-condition notations.